# Booting to Windows with broken GRUB

Tags: boot, windows, grub2

I installed Ubuntu on my Windows 10 system, to dual boot with [GRUB](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html). Ubuntu and GRUB were installed on a separate drive from the main Windows drive.

Later on, I did not need Ubuntu on my system anymore, so I followed directions given in another post. I went to Partition Manager in Windows, deleted the two partitions that belonged to Ubuntu, and rebooted to test it.

Now the Windows Boot Manager is nowhere to be found, and I cannot get past the GRUB rescue prompt. I have a Windows install disk and an Ubuntu LiveCD, both of which I've tried to use to save my system. Nothing is working for me, however. I've tried everything I could find online, and no command or boot loader replacement has worked.

I just need to boot to Windows.

Comment: You have to restore your MBR. There are many guides  Look for "windows restore MBR". You will need a windows disc to boot from, and then type some commands on the terminal (windows of course).

Comment: @guillermochamorro Whether that is on-topic on a Unix group, that is another story. Beware we are in a post MBR world though. ;)

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I was just to write a comment about that. I guess fixing *windows* boot is out of the scope of this site.

Comment: If you got EFI, check if there is the option "windows boot manager" and set it as the first boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you installed Ubuntu, where did you tell it to put GRUB? If you told it to put it in one of the Ubuntu partitions, it will fail once you erased them.

First, go into the BIOS/UEFI/Firmware settings of the PC. Is the Windows/NTFS drive set as the boot device? If not, change the boot device to the Windows Boot Manager on the Windows/NTFS drive and reboot.

There's [another solution at Dell support](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln300987/how-to-repair-the-efi-bootloader-on-a-gpt-hdd-for-windows-7-8-8-1-and-10-on-your-dell-pc?lang=en) which is universal, will work on any PC, but depends on your knowing whether your drive was partitioned with a EFI (GPT)  or MBR partition table. If Windows 10 was the first OS on this PC or if the drive was wiped before installation, it's EFI/GPT for sure. There are three tabs on that web page; make sure to click on the third tab for windows 10!

Several more solutions are at [GroovyPost](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/fix-windows-10-wont-boot-startup-repair-bootrec/).

Should that fail, reboot with a LiveUSB and an external drive, back up everything important from the NTFS partition, and reinstall Windows from scratch.  Windows 10 prefers EFI and a GPT partition table over MBR ('BIOS'), just like Ubuntu does nowadays.

Comment: I have to do that? There isn't any way to boot to Windows? Well, I suppose it'll be worth it. I need to upgrade my SSD, anyways.

Comment: See another idea I had, above in the second graf.

Comment: It doesn't seem as though there's anything to boot related to the Windows drive. Looks like I'll have to go the hard route.

Comment: @WAUthethird If you got EFI, check if there is the option "windows boot manager" and set it as the first boot.

Comment: @guillermochamorro There is not a bootable drive or partition with that label. The only bootable drive in my system is the one I installed GRUB on.

Comment: Then it's definitely New Drive Time, glad you're prepared for a new SSD! I would not trust the old drive until you've done a thorough SMART run and a torture test with stress-ng

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to **Fix the MBR in Windows 10** in the following [link](https://neosmart.net/wiki/fix-mbr/). I have also faced such problem many time and it always solves them.

You have removed the ubuntu but did not fix the mbr to boot, rather than grub so it cannot find your os.